# Console Command module (in-game console or base for script engine)

Tags: c++, c++11, console, template, template-meta-programming

I've created a console/terminal command handling module that allows the programmer to bind functions to a command name and later execute them from std::string. What's new is that it handles most stuff automatically and allows for usage such as:

```
void func1_ptr(const std::string& name) {
    std::cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << std::endl;
}

std::function<void(float)> func2_wrapper = [](float x) {
    std::cout << x << "^2 = " << x*x << std::endl;
}

auto func3_lambda = [](int x, float y, const std::string& z) {
    std::cout << x << y << z << std::endl;
}

/* ... */

CommandConsole cmd;

cmd.bind("func1", func_ptr);      // default parser, types are infered from function
cmd.bind("func2", func2_wrapper); // default parser, types are infered from function
// custom parser (needed for lambdas)
cmd.bind("func3", func3_lambda, Parser::BasicParser::parse<int, float, std::string>);

cmd.execute("func1 John"); // func1_ptr("John")
cmd.execute("func2 11.0"); // func2_wrapper(11.0f)
cmd.execute("func3 0 3.14 \"hello world\""); // func3_lambda(0, 3.14f, "hello world")
```

Under the hood it uses tuples, variadic templates and metaprogramming magic to deduce types, parse input according to types of function's arguments and invoke function with parsed parameteres. Any advices/tips would be welcome. :)

---

## Code

#### CommandConsole.hpp

Command console object. It stores binded functions and executes them using parsers. Parser is a function `p` that takes two arguments - function `f` and `std::string` containing arguments for that function to be invoked with (just like `char* argv[]` from `main()`). It parses given string to get arguments for `f` and invokes it with them. Generic multi-purpouse parser is available (`Parser::BasicParser` template).

```
class CommandConsole {
    public:
        // Bind command with function using custom parser
        template<typename Func, typename FuncParser>
        void bind(const std::string& cmdName, const Func& func, const FuncParser& funcParser) {
            _command_parsers[cmdName] = std::bind(funcParser, func, std::placeholders::_1);
        }

        // Bind command with function using default (basic) parser - std::function wrapper
        template<typename... FuncArgs>
        void bind(const std::string& cmdName, const std::function<void(FuncArgs...)>& func) {
            bind(cmdName, func, Parser::BasicParser::parse<FuncArgs...>);
        }

        // Bind command with function using default (basic) parser - function pointer
        template<typename... FuncArgs>
        void bind(const std::string& cmdName, void(*func)(FuncArgs...)) {
            bind(cmdName, func, Parser::BasicParser::parse<FuncArgs...>);
        }


        // Execute command with given arguments
        void execute(const std::string& command) {
            // Command name
            std::size_t name_pos = command.find_first_not_of(" \t\r\n");
            std::size_t name_end = command.find_first_of(" \t\r\n", name_pos);
            std::size_t name_len =
                (name_pos != std::string::npos) ?
                ((name_end == std::string::npos ? command.length() : name_end) - name_pos) : 0;

            // Arguments
            std::size_t args_pos = std::min(name_pos + name_len + 1, command.length());
            std::size_t args_end = command.find_last_not_of(" \t\r\n");
            std::size_t args_len = std::max(args_pos, args_end) - args_pos + 1;

            // Values
            std::string cmd_name = (name_len > 0) ? command.substr(name_pos, name_len) : "";
            std::string cmd_args = (name_len > 0) ? command.substr(args_pos, args_len) : "";

            // Execution
            if(_command_parsers.count(cmd_name) > 0)
                _command_parsers[cmd_name](cmd_args);
        }

    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&)>> _command_parsers;
};
```

#### BasicParser

Template function `Parser::BasicParser::parse<Ts...>(Function f, string args)`. Parses `args` to `std::tuple<Ts...>` and then unwrapes it to use as arguments for `f`. `Parser::BasicParser::parseFirstArg(string args)` return pair of string - first parsed argument from `args` and rest of `args` without first argument bo parsed next.

```
namespace Parser 
{

    namespace BasicParser
    {

        /**
        * Forward declaration
        */
        namespace detail
        {
            template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
            std::tuple<T, U, Args...> ArgToTupleSplitter(const std::string& str);

            template<typename T>
            std::tuple<T> ArgToTupleSplitter(const std::string& str);
        }


        /**
         * Basic Parser
         */
        template<typename... Ts>
        void parse(const std::function<void(Ts...)>& func, const std::string& cmdArgs) {
            // Remove references in types to avoid conversion problems
            std::tuple<typename std::remove_reference<Ts>::type...> tupledArgs =
                detail::ArgToTupleSplitter<typename std::remove_reference<Ts>::type...>(cmdArgs);

            CmdArgApplyer::apply(func, tupledArgs);
        }

        /**
         * Basic parser - Specialization for commands with 0 arguments.
         *                Any passed arguments are ignored.
         */
        template<>
        void parse<>(const std::function<void()>& func, const std::string& cmdArgs) {
            (void) cmdArgs; // unused parameter warning

            func();
        }

        /**
         * Basic argument parsing - returns tuple <arg0, rest>
         */
        std::tuple<std::string, std::string> parseFirstArg(const std::string& args) {
            std::size_t i = 0, j = 0, k; // first argument is substring of range [i, j] in 'args'

            // Skip whitespaces before argument
            while(i < args.length() && std::isspace(args[i]))
                ++i;

            // If all characters are whitespaces, return empty argument
            if(i == args.length())
                return std::make_tuple(std::string(""), std::string(""));


            if(args[i] == '\"') {
                // If argument starts with opening ", then look for closing "
                j = ++i;

                while(j < args.length() && args[j] != '\"')
                    ++j;

            } else {
                // If argument starts from anything else, it ends upon first whitespace
                j = i + 1;

                while(j < args.length() && !std::isspace(args[j]))
                    ++j;
            }

            // Verify that k is in [0, args.length()] range and remove whitespaces from left side
            k = std::min(j + 1, args.length());
            while(k < args.length() && isspace(args[k]))
                ++k;

            return std::make_tuple(args.substr(i, j - i), args.substr(k));
        }


        /***************************************************************************************/


        namespace detail
        {
            /**
             * ArgToTupleSplitter<T, U, Args...> - splits arguments in std::string to std::tuple<T, U, Args...> between whitespaces.
             *                                     Last argument uses what's left in argument list.
             *
             * T - current argument type
             * U - next argument type
             * Args... - possible next argument types
             */
            template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
            std::tuple<T, U, Args...> ArgToTupleSplitter(const std::string& str) {
                std::tuple<std::string, std::string> parsedArgs = parseFirstArg(str);
                std::string& this_arg  = std::get<0>(parsedArgs);
                std::string& rest_args = std::get<1>(parsedArgs);

                return std::tuple_cat(
                    std::make_tuple(Parser::detail::CmdArgConvert<std::string, T>{}(this_arg)),     // this argument
                    ArgToTupleSplitter<U, Args...>(rest_args)                                       // rest of arguments
                );
            }

            /**
             * ArgToTupleSplitter<T> - specialization to ArgToTupleSplitter<T, U, Args...> which handles last argument.
             *                         This method uses as argument's source whole string, not only till first whitespace!
             *
             * T - current argument type
             */
            template<typename T>
            std::tuple<T> ArgToTupleSplitter(const std::string& str) {
                return std::make_tuple(Parser::detail::CmdArgConvert<std::string, T>{}(str));
            }

        }

    }

}
```

#### CmdArgApplier

Helper module that takes as arguments function and tuple, unwraps tuple and invokes function with tuple's values as arguments.

```
namespace Parser
{

    namespace CmdArgApplier
    {
        /**
         * Forward declaration
         */
        namespace detail
        {
            template <std::size_t N>
            struct CmdArgApplier_Helper;
        }


        /**
         * CmdArgApplier 
         */
        template<typename Func, typename... Args>
        void apply(const Func& func, const std::tuple<Args...>& args) {
            detail::CmdArgApplier_Helper< std::tuple_size<std::tuple<Func, Args...>>::value - 1 >::apply(func, args);
        }



        /************************************************************/


        namespace detail
        {
            template <std::size_t N>
            struct CmdArgApplier_Helper
            {
                template <typename Func, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
                static void apply(const Func& func, const Tuple& tuple, const Args&... args) {
                    CmdArgApplier_Helper<N - 1>::apply(func, tuple, std::get<N - 1>(tuple), args...);
                }
            };

            template <>
            struct CmdArgApplier_Helper<0>
            {
                template <typename Func, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
                static void apply(const Func& func, const Tuple& tuple, const Args&... args) {
                    (void) tuple; // unused argument warning

                    func(args...);
                }
            };
        }
    }

}
```

#### CmdArgConverter

Template `<F, T>` that helps convert value of type `F` to type `T`. Unified interface.

```
namespace Parser
{
    namespace detail
    {
        /**
         * CmdArgConverter - template functors used to convert current argument from std::string to given type
         *                   In default version, it uses constructor with FROM-type argument.
         *
         * FROM - type from which current argument will be converted, usually std::string
         * TO   - type to which you current argument will be converted
         */
        template<typename FROM, typename TO>
        class CmdArgConvert {
        public:
            TO operator()(const FROM& from) { return TO(from); }
        };

        /**
         * String to int converter
         */
        template<>
        class CmdArgConvert<std::string, int> {
        public:
            int operator()(const std::string& from) { return std::stoi(from); }
        };

        /*** a lot more... ***/

    }

}
```

Comment: Are these your actual variable and function names? The comments indicate a lot of code has been snipped. That's often unnecessarily hard on the reviewers and sometimes renders the question [off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Mast: Yes, this is how the code actually was written. I've read here on another question that one shouldn't use long names when you can write it in shortcut. Func - function, cmd - command, arg - argument, pos - position, len - length etc.  Is it generally considered bad practice?

Comment: I also posted it on [Github](https://github.com/RippeR37/SLACC) - its 100% working code. Comments are to explain what given function/part of code does (or to help me remember what was the idea behind this code `;)`).

Comment: Where did you find that advice? Shortened names are ok as long as they aren't ambiguous, but I see a lot of 1-character variables in your code which are definitely bad practice. This will probably be pointed out in one of the answers.

Comment: It's C++, not JavaScript :-)

Comment: @Mast: it was about variables with names from 4-5 words (~20 characters long), to shorten them a little, not about ~8characters long to 2-3. I though you were taking about variables like `cmd_name` and forgot about `i, j, k`. For my defense - it's really hard for me to name 'iterartors'/indices and i did comment what's their purpouse, but yeah, renaming them is good idea. `:)` I can't find it now, it was C# or Java question and it was in comment, not answer.